# R rms error message "has <2 category labels"

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to map a continuous variable ("relative_frequency_total") to binary values ("topicality"). All values above a certain threshold should be mapped to one, all below or equal to it to the other value. Since I want the resulting variable to stay as predictive as possible, I first take each decile of the continuous variable, try mapping relative_frequency_total using that decile as the cutoff point, feed the resulting binary variable into a logistic regression model, and remember that model's R2, like this:

```
quant_eval = data.frame("quantile" = numeric(100), "R2" = numeric(100))
counter = 1
for(q in seq(1,11,by=1)){
    dom$topicality[dom$ranked_frequency_total > quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total)[q]] <- "topical"
    dom$topicality[dom$ranked_frequency_total <= quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total)[q]] <- "non-topical"
    tmp.lrm <- lrm(DOM ~ as.factor(topicality), data=dom)
    quant_eval[counter,"quantile"] = q
    quant_eval[counter,"R2"] = tmp.lrm$stats["R2"]
    counter = counter+1
}
quant_eval
```

Now here are my questions:

(1) This works well with quantiles 1-4, but at the 5th I get an error message saying "topicality has <2 category levels". What does that mean?

(2) What really confuses me is that this error message seems to depend on the order in which I try the quantiles. For instance, when I try quantile 1 or 10 without the loop, everything's fine. When I try quantile 5 in isolation I get the error message, and when I try 1 and 10 again after that I also get it. Does lrm() somehow remember what I did last, or why is this? 
I also thought that the reason could be that I reuse the same column again and again for mapping ranked_frequency_total, but then I tried renaming the column ea

The original dataframe dom is rather huge, but for me the error message is repeatable with the following extract:

```
   DOM relative_frequency_total
1  DAT             0.0203549061
2  DAT             0.0203549061
3  NOM             0.0005219207
4  NOM             0.0005219207
5  NOM             0.0005219207
6  NOM             0.0005219207
7  NOM             0.0015657620
8  NOM             0.0015657620
9  NOM             0.0015657620
10 NOM             0.0005219207
11 NOM             0.0005219207
12 NOM             0.0010438413
13 NOM             0.0010438413
14 NOM             0.0041753653
15 NOM             0.0005219207
16 NOM             0.0005219207
17 NOM             0.0041753653
18 NOM             0.0005219207
19 NOM             0.0010438413
20 NOM             0.0020876827
```

Comment: Instead of cutting and pasting your `data.frame`, use `dput(dom)` or `dput(head(dom))` so we can just cut and paste.

Comment: You also appear to be missing `dom$ranked_frequency_total`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for `?quantile`. When you run `quantile` at default, it will give you quintiles (exactly cut points).

```
quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
0.001747327 0.007373624 0.012441222 0.015827876 0.020194380
```

What is happening is that when you reach q=5, *all* of `relative_frequency_total` is less than or equal to quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total)[5], which by definition is the maximum of `dom$ranked_frequency_total`. So, *all* of your independent variable is exactly the same, which means that you no longer have two factor levels, but one.

I am guessing that you want to split into deciles, so you could use:

```
quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total,probs=seq(0,1,0.1))
```

But then make sure to only go up to 9, so that you don't get the same problem.

```
# Only set the rows you need
# quant_eval = data.frame("quantile" = numeric(100), "R2" = numeric(100))
quant_eval = data.frame("quantile" = numeric(9), "R2" = numeric(9))
# counter = 1 # No need for counter, just use q
for(q in 1:9){
    # ifelse works nice here
    # dom$topicality[dom$ranked_frequency_total > quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total)[q]]     <- "topical"
    # dom$topicality[dom$ranked_frequency_total <= quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total)[q]] <- "non-topical"
    dom$topicality=ifelse(dom$ranked_frequency_total > quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total,probs=seq(0,1,0.1))[q],'topical','non-topical')
    tmp.lrm <- lrm(DOM ~ as.factor(topicality), data=dom)
    quant_eval[q,"quantile"] = q
    quant_eval[q,"R2"] = tmp.lrm$stats["R2"]
    # counter = counter+1
}
```

But you could also get a little more elegant.

```
cut.points=10
quan.r2=function(q) {
    topicality=ifelse(dom$ranked_frequency_total > quantile(dom$ranked_frequency_total,probs=seq(0,1,1/cut.points))[q],'topical','non-topical')
    c(quantile=q,lrm(DOM ~ as.factor(topicality), data=dom)$stats['R2'])
}
t(sapply(seq(cut.points-1),quan.r2))

      quantile         R2
 [1,]        1 0.02216367
 [2,]        2 0.04580822
 [3,]        3 0.09620369
 [4,]        4 0.49200275
 [5,]        5 0.37952599
 [6,]        6 0.29053577
 [7,]        7 0.21660100
 [8,]        8 0.15282620
 [9,]        9 0.09620369
```