# “has <2 category labels” error R

Tags: r

I searched the forum and found this very similar question: [R rms error message "has <2 category labels"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671900/r-rms-error-message-has-2-category-labels), but I just can't figure it out how the answer can help my problem.

I am using the rms package, and while using the OLS function I encounter the error:

```
reg_a <- ols(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 
         + x7 + emplrel + x8 + country.x + x9 + x10, weights=w,
         data=db_c_a, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

> Error in catg(xi, name = nam, label = lab) : 
>   emplrel has <2 category levels

This problem seems very straightforward, but the issue is that my "emplrel" variable *does* have more than two category levels, or at least it seems to me to have. For example, using *str(emplrel)* gets:

> str(db_c_a$emplrel):
>    Factor w/ 3 levels "Employee","Self-employed",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...

Or by using table:

> table(db_c_a$emplrel):
>   Employee  2063
>   Self-employed Working for own family 863
>   business   148

So I don't know what exactly is the problem.